# How do I cleanly update a large element's content in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website that lets the user go through several stages of a generator, and I want to do it on one HTML page. The current way I'm trying to do this is by updating a div's innerHTML, but that gets very long and complicated fast. Is there a way to write the content in a separate HTML file, then import it & update the element when a javascript function is called?

```
function stepTwo() {
    document.getElementById("mainText").innerHTML = `
    <h3>Question two</h3>
    <select id = "gender">
        <option value = "male">Male</option><option value = "female"> Female</option>
        <option value = "non-binary">Non-binary</option>...
    </select>
    <a LOT more lines>
    `
}
```

Obviously this is very ugly. I'm looking for any way to clean it up, be it by importing another HTML file or some other way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to use a javascript framework/library such as svelte, angular or react.

Comment: "Is there a way to write the content in a separate HTML file, then import it & update the element when a javascript function is called?" Yes, look into AJAX and `.fetch()`

Comment: A simpler solution might be that you render all your staged in your HTML before anything starts, and you use Javascript to make each stage visible/invisible as you go through the stages. Frameworks are in many cases overkill and have serious drawbacks.

Comment: you could create the HTML in your backend, PHP for example and then use include to call that piece of code in there

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can separate the content into separate HTML files and dynamically load them into your main HTML page using JavaScript.

1. Create separate HTML files for each stage of the generator
2. In your main HTML file, create a  or any other container element
3. you can use AJAX to load the content from the separate HTML files and update the content container when a function is called.

```
function loadStage(stageNumber) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'stage' + stageNumber + '.html', // Replace with the correct file name
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#contentContainer').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Failed to load stage ' + stageNumber + ' content.');
    }
  });
}

loadStage(1);
```

This helps simplify your code and makes it easier to manage the content for each stage of your generator